# Is this bash variable setting way correct

Tags: bash, variables

Is this  bash variable setting way correct? Please provide some in-depth description on this usage.

```
: ${AA="/root/"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use this form to set some default values. For example

```
default="/root"
read -p "What is the directory? [$default] " AA
: ${AA:=$default}  
echo "Using: $AA"
```

Note I added a colon in `${AA:=...}` so that the substitution happens if the variable is empty, not just unset (because here it is set).

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual. The `:` command is [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).